# Android Vision Text scanning leaks memory in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, ocr, android-vision

After noticing a few crashes on older devices when using `TextRecognizer` from the library `Android.Gms.Vision` I decided to profile it using Android Studio and the result was the following:

[image]

While the process is running, even if the method `ReceiveDetections` is empty (no code logic on my side other than instantiating the builder), the memory usage grows really fast, and the app subsequently crashes within one minute. From the profiler I could see that the memory is used in a `byte[]` variable in the native code.

The interesting fact is that I'm also using the `BarcodeDetector` from that library, but that's not causing any memory leak. Finally, I also profiled my Xamarin.Android application using the Xamarin profiler, and the Mono code is taking at most a couple of MB, so my code doesn't seem to cause the problem.

I add the code I'm using below:

```
public class Scanning : Activity, ISurfaceHolderCallback, IProcessor
{
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private const int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                    cameraSource.Start(surfaceView.Holder);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Scanning);
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

        surfaceView = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surfaceView);

        TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();

        if (textRecognizer.IsOperational)
        {
            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(ApplicationContext, textRecognizer).Build();

            surfaceView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
            textRecognizer.SetProcessor(this);
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height) { }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
        {
            RequestPermissions(new string[]
            {
                Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera
            }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
            return;
        }

        cameraSource.Start(surfaceView.Holder);
    }

    public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        cameraSource.Stop();
    }

    public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections) { }

    public void Release() { }
}
```

Am I missing anything on my side, or is it an actual bug of the library?

If yes is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

MCWs Managed Callable Wrappers (C# code wrapping Android API) might hold reference to some java objects containing other data (Image scanned, text...), so that GC cannot release that memory.

I had similar case in one custom bindings for image recognition.

The solution is to understand which objects might hold references and after they are not needed anymore to manually call `GC.Collect()`.

From this high level view (glance) I would call it in `Release()` and/or after `cameraSource.Stop();`

Let me know if that works. Otherwise I'll need repro sample to test it.

Comment: To be honest my Huawei has a good memory management and was handling that for a couple of minutes, the problem was with Samsungs (unfortunately people in my team with other devices left already so I can't give you a proper answer). I tried to call the garbage collector after every scan, but the difference is not really noticeable. Xamarin added the issue in the pipeline and hopefully will be fixed https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/projects/1